# How to install Pear Linux's shell in Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments

For people who doesn't know what Pear Linux is:

> [Pear Linux](http://pearlinux.fr/) is a French Ubuntu-based desktop Linux distribution.
>   Some of its features include ease-of-use, custom user interface with a
>   Mac OS X-style dockbar, and out-of-the-box support for many popular
>   multimedia codecs.

Excerpt from [Distrowatch](http://www.distrowatch.com).

When this Linux Distribution came out, I immediately went to the website and found out that Pear Linux is actually Mac OSX with a pear.

[image]

I was going to download it and install Pear Linux as a triple-boot on my computer (Windows and Ubuntu installed).

Then I remembered that Pear Linux is Ubuntu based.  So I thought of a better Idea of installing only the Comice OS Shell in Ubuntu(the Desktop environment of Pear Linux), so that I can select that in the login screen.

Is that possible?

EDIt: Found [this](http://pearlinux.org/index.php/forum/2-installation/1363-update-version-of-comice-os-shell-4-0-2).

Comment: Add their repositories, update your sources list, search for the package in Synaptic, install it, do not do anything but that, disable their repositories, select it at login, looks nothing more than a Theme for Gnome Shell to me anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's another Linux distribution entirely, even if it's based on Ubuntu you have no idea what they've changed and what's different from the Ubuntu version you are running now. The way I see it, you have two options:

- Try and find a theme that emulates that screenshot. It looks to me like nothing more than a theme and a dock, and you can add that yourself without too much hassle. There's plenty of guides around on how to make your Ubuntu look different.
- Remove Ubuntu and install that distribution instead. As I said, it's another distribution entirely. If their only contribution is changing the theme, I'd be suspicious to begin with as that doesn't seem very serious.

I'd highly recommend modding your current Ubuntu variant and stay away from Pear Linux, but if you want to try it you should try it as a clean install (or in a VM).